# What does "an outfit to [wear to] prom out of duct tape" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Does it mean "an outfit made of duct tape" or "an outfit to walk without be jammed in duct tape"?
I used this link: https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/prom?q=prom

"There's a scholarship from the Klingon Language Institute where you have to be a Star Trek fan. I won a scholarship for writing an essay about George Washington's crossing of the Delaware River," he says. "There are ones where you do an art project, a science project. There's one where you make an outfit to [wear to] prom out of duct tape."

Source: https://www.cnbc.com/2017/10/31/this-ceo-paid-for-harvard-with-24-scholarships-totaling-90000.html

Answer (score 1):

It is "*the outfit that is made out of duct tape*". The sentence clearly states this. You can wear such an outfit to prom.

It's probably another one of those reduced relative clauses.

Comment: [Here](https://www.google.com/search?q=duct+tape+prom+dress&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj7lcbY3J3XAhVE04MKHepVB2wQsAQIJw&biw=1366&bih=647) are some images.